# Fresh download -> Error: "MuleStudio.app is damaged and can't be opened."

Tags: java, macos, mule-studio

Trying to install Mulesoft's developer studio.  Did a fresh download of `MuleStudio-for-macosx-64bit-3.5.0-201312091746.zip` from http://www.mulesoft.org/thank-you-downloading-mule-studio-mac and unzipped, can't run the `MuleSoft.app` file.

Only options are to Cancel or "Move to Trash"

Things I've checked:

- The checksum is correct: `42433b0ed8e82e969111799f7a2d136c`
- I tried the Control-Click to open, same problem.
- Tried re-unzipping it.
- Java 7, `1.7.0_45 64bit`
- Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 and up to date

Comment: Did you redownload it? Sometimes downloads can be corrupted.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: He validated the checksum, so the download is unlikely to be corrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is from the Gatekeeper security system built into OS X. According to the [help page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290), this particular message can appear if the application package has been tampered with (e.g. its signature no longer matches the developer's certificate).

This may be harmless, or it may be an indication that the package has been hijacked and contains malicious code. The former is probably more likely, but I would email the developers before opening the package, just to be sure.

The [help page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290) for Gatekeeper gives more details, including disabling the feature if you'd like to go ahead and launch the app anyway.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that worked.  Since the checksum was OK, I decided to try it; turning that setting back off now!  I'll try to get word to the developer.